# programming IDE in Android market

Tags: android, ide

Is there a programming IDE in Android market? Or just an editor that gives certain supportung features like syntax highlighting?

Comment: For what purpose are you needing this?

Comment: Never tried this, but could be what you are searching for: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1340852

Comment: an IDE on android, what for ?

Comment: just want to do some coding on my phone or tablet, and save it or send it to some online IDE like [this one](http://http://ideone.com)

Comment: why do you down vote the question?i code on my rezound in coffee shops all the time. i ssh to a cluster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution I've seen so far is Terminal IDE : https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&rdid=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&rdot=1

Includes fully configured VIM, Java & Java compiler, busybox, ...

Comment: i wish it had gcc and g++. and if it had that, i'd with it had all the other utilities to compile stuff. boost would be nice. well, i hope someone ports archlinux :-)

Comment: This is one of the best apps I've seen on Android.

Answer (score 1):

BRexx (Rexx) and Ruboto IRB (Ruby) include IDE & runtime as well...I´ve tried both of them, they run pretty stable!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good Blog on [Programming for Android on Android](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australian-technology/programming-for-android-on-android/). It describes the features, pros and cons of 4 IDEs.

1. Anjedi
2. DroidDevelop/JavaIDEDroid
3. Terminal IDE
4. AIDE

Or if you are looking for other language IDEs. Then have a look at [15 Apps for Programming on Android](http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/developer/15-apps-for-programming-on-android/).

Also have a look at : Touchqode